# got UICC carrier priviliges but failed to open channel in android 5.1

Tags: android, smartcard, telephonymanager, apdu, sim-card

I am trying to develop some functions with newly added UICC features in  TelephonyManager in android 5.1,

using these configuration in my UICC and got UICC carrier privileges already.
( refer to https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/uicc.html )

my UICC configuration in TLV format :

```
FF40 
81 A8
E2 3E
E1 30 //UICC rule
   C1 14 CD AE 0D 74 62 B8 ED 7D 58 68 59 23 16 45 E9 7C A5 DA 1F 90
   CA 18 63 6f 6d 2e 74 61 69 73 79 73 2e 73 6d 61 72 74 63 61 72 64 74 65 73 74                      
E3 0A DB 08 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
E2 32 //SEEK smartcard api AID and hash
E1 28 
   4F 10 01 A4 04 00 0B A0 00 00 00 18 47 50 41 43 2D 31  //AID
   C1 14 EA 76 BC 02 00 00 3B 6E 0C 58 12 72 37 F4 1F F9 78 FC 10 6B //sha-1 hash
E3 06 //SEEK smartcard api rule
   D0 01 01 
   D1 01 01
E2 32 
   E1 28 //uicc privilege AID and hash
   4F 10 01 A4 04 00 0B A0 00 00 00 18 47 50 41 43 2D 32 
   C1 14 CD AE 0D 74 62 B8 ED 7D 58 68 59 23 16 45 E9 7C A5 DA 1F 90
E3  06 
   D0 01 01 
   D1 01 01
```

but after getting UICC privileges and trying to open iccOpenLogicalChannel, This is the stack trace I get when calling one of the above functions:
    "java.lang.SecurityException: Only Smartcard API may access UICC"

How to modify the UICC configuration and open channel successfully in Telephonymanager ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You may find this conversation interesting: https://github.com/CellularPrivacy/Android-IMSI-Catcher-Detector/issues/96

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: Dear Sir, 
I using Huawei Mate8 , and this shows "only smartcard api may access UICC". it's cpu is kirin 950 , android 6.0.
some updates, 
I test these phones. 
    sony Z2 (Qualcomm S801)   => privilege get , can send APDU to UICC  
  ,  Xiaomi M5(Qualcomm S820) => can't get privilege  , can send APDU to UICC   
  ,  Redmi Note3 (Qualcomm S650) => passed , can send APDU to UICC

Comment: maybe depend on brand own OS version and CPU type ?